# Change WHMCS template by custom field

Tags: smarty, hook, whmcs

maybe somebody can help me with this.

I have 2 brands working in 1 whmcs, i used a **custom field** called **"Provider"** and according to that email designs and template is being loaded now. But!

I need or want that if a customer login to whmcs, if he has selected provider X load template X and if i his profile he has selected provider Y load template Y.

Any idea about how can i do this via hook? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can change template on the fly by setting `systpl` variable in the url to the desired template folder, as mentioned in the [Testing docs](https://developers.whmcs.com/themes/testing/), for example:

https://example.com/index.php?systpl=template-x

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answer.

My question was focused to this "I need or want that if a customer login to whmcs, if he has selected provider X load template X and if i his profile he has selected provider Y load template Y."

I mean, that i need that template being loaded not via URL, but, detect a custom field and load a determinated template according to that.

Some idea?

Thank you!

Comment: you should've updated your question to clarify your needs, other developers will think this is an answer and won't read it. Also you can comment under the my answer if you like. Keep this in mind for future questions ;)

Comment: Regarding your question, I am not aware of any method besides redirecting to the given URL.